# Browsersync вызывает ошибку "Refused to execute inline script ... " в SPA на некорневых маршрутах

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router, browsersync

Я увидел в консоли браузера во время просмотра своего SPA следующее сообщение:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security 
Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, 
a hash ('sha256-KpHv3zgivMSB4dPnfYfqMt2lBibsYvM36EdoBBAsfbM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') 
is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, 
so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Данная ошибка вызвана [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/):

[image]

Об этой ошибке известно следующее:

1. Она возникает только если перезагрузка браузера произойдёт в некорневом маршруте, то есть на `http://localhost:3001` этой ошибки никогда не будет, а, например, на `http://localhost:3001/sign-in` и других некорневых маршрутах она произойдёт при первой же автоматической перезагрузки страницы.
2. При возникновении этой ошибки на странице ничего не отображается, кроме `cannot get /sign-in`.
3. Данная ошибка возникает только в SPA, где маршрутизация осуществляется средствами HTML History API, а конкретно в данном случае - посредством `vue-router`. При тех же настройках во время разработки обычных сайтов без использания HTML History API, такой ошибки не вознакает ни на каких страницах.

### Почему я использую browsersync, а не webpack-dev-server?

Для универсальности. Поддерживать несколько gulp/webpack-пресетов для разных типов проектов - затратно, требуется унификация. В любом случае, переход на `webpack-dev-server` невозможен, потому что он перезагружает страницу только при изменении файлов, входящих в webpack-бандл, а помимо этого могут быть независимые от webpack-бандла стили, шаблоны и т. д. Такие рекомендации, как "а вы всё в webpack-бандл добавляйте" лишают гибкости, что также не нехорошо с точти зрения проектирования систем.

Comment: Другой вариант: добавить пакет 'browser-sync-spa', см. подробнее тут:
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-spa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-spa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, будет ли это лучшим решением, но для ваших потребностей думаю подойдёт. Вы можете установить расширение для браузера, чтобы избежать ошибки CSP ([Подробнее здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/CSP))

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Насчёт решения понял, но не могли бы Вы сделать небольшой комментарий по поводу причин возникновения данной ошибки?